# jQuery: How to insert or remove a .js file at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, append

i want to add a .js file after a link has been clicked.
The .js file is a script, that has no function to call directly, but the file has to be inserted in the body part of the site.

Another solution would be, if the file is called at page load and if the click event of the link is called, then remove the .js file.

I've tried something like this, but nothing happens:

```
$(".myLink").click(function(){
    $.getScript("myJavascriptFile.js");
});
```

and also here:

```
$(".myLink").click(function(){
var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = "app_javascript/dragscroll.js";
        $(".myDiv").append(script); // or  $("body").append(script);
});
```

Comment: What do you think is the benefit in removing a JS file?

Comment: I need to do that for testing and presenting this function. there are three different types of this function and they should appear after clicking a link e.g. "test function 2". two of the three functions can be called directly with a function (callFunction1();), but the third has to be included without calling a function.

Comment: Why would you add/remove scripts like this? Is is very big?

Comment: it's this http://scripterlative.com?dragscroll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, actually, "nothing happens" sounds most probably too loud. 
getScript is by all means asynchronous, so you should provide any code, which relies on using this script in load handler, which is actually, the second param.

`$.getScript('here_comes_the_script.js', function(){...//here comes the code})`

You can use some wrapping to make thing more flexible - by passing events to load handler, something like this:

```
getScriptDetectable = function(src) {
     getScript(src, function() {
      $(document).trigger("new_script", {src: src})
     });
}
```

But this, of course, doesn't free you from considering the fact that this code is asynchronous.

And about removing script. There is actually no general way to make browser "unsee" the code.

You can try do something like:

```
var src = document.querySelector('script');
src.parentNode.removeChild(src);
```

but all code in this file which has been evaluated already is evaluated, so there is no much sense in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery function for that - `jQuery.getScript()`. It appends the script tag to the body, so it does exactly what you want.

I do not think removing this tag will disable the code - you would need to separately delete all the defined global functions, unbind the event handlers etc.